# Problemas na identificação da div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estou tentando fazer uma lista de tarefas be simples onde tenha inserçao de tarefas dinamicamente, existe uma checkbox em cada tarefa que ao ser marcada coloca um line-through no texto, mas ao fazer isso ele sempre coloca na primeira tarefas e nas outras nao faz nada, gostaria de saber se tem como identificar cada uma, mantendo ela dinamica, segue abaixo o codigo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) $('#button').click();
    });
    
    $('#button').click(function(){
        var textAdd = $('#inpudAdd').val();
        $('#inpudAdd').val('');
        $('#div').append('<div id = divinha><input class = "mano" id = "check" type="checkbox"> ' + textAdd +'<img id = "lixo" src="imagens/lixeira.png" alt="" height="20px">' +'</div>');
    });
    $(document).on("change","#check",function(){


    
        if ($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            $('#divinha').addClass('marcar');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#divinha').removeClass('marcar');
        }
    
    });

    /*$(document).on("click.primeiro",'#check', function() {
        $('#divinha').addClass('seila');
        console.log("meu");
    });
    $(document).on("click.segundo",'#check', function() {
        $('#divinha').removeClass('seila')
        console.log("meu");
    });*/
    $(document).on("click",'#lixo', function() {
        if(confirm("Voce realmente deseja excluir esse item?")==true){
            $('#divinha').remove();
        }

    });
});
```

```css
.marcar{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
.CentralizarDiv{

    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 70vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
.centralizarInp{
    
    width: 50%;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

    
}
.centralizarBut{
    
    width: 50%;
    display:block;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
h2{
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}
table{
    
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.secBut{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src = "js/js.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Lista de Tarefas</h2>
        <input class="centralizarInp" type="text" name="checkListItem" id="inpudAdd"/>
        <button class = "centralizarBut " id="button">OK</button>
        <table >
            <tr><td><button id = "incopleto" class="secBut">Em Progresso</button></td>
            <td><button id = "completo"class="secBut">Finalizadas</button></td>
            <td><button id = "todos" class="secBut">Todos</button></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        
        <div class="CentralizarDiv" id= "div" ></div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver o problema proposto na pergunta, que é selecionar o `<div>` ao qual pertence o `checkbox` que foi clicado, você pode usar o método jQuery [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) que irá retorna o pai de um elemento no caso o objeto que irá gerar o evento.

Também é possível simplificar o evento `change` do `checkbox` substituindo todo bloco de teste derivado da condição `is(":checked")` pelo método jQuery [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) que adiciona ou remove uma ou mais classes de cada elemento no elementos, ou conjunto de elementos, dependendo da presença da classe.

Um problema que pude verificar no seu código é o compartilhamento do atributo `id` entre os elementos dinâmicos. A [recomendação do HTML5 no que se refere ao atributo `id`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) é taxativa:

> O atributo `id` especifica o identificador exclusivo (ID) do seu
>   elemento. O valor deve ser exclusivo entre todos os IDs na subárvore
>   inicial do elemento e deve conter pelo menos um caractere. O valor não
>   deve conter caracteres de espaço.

No caso todos os elementos `div` criados dinamicamente estão recebendo o mesmo `id`

```
  <div id = divinha>
```

Os navegadores até o momento são tolerantes com o descumprimento dessa regra, mas é uma boa prática a respeitar pois:

- caso precise validar o seu código(requisição de uma empresa ou um TCC) o HTML gerado não será aprovado.
- caso em um determinado momento os fabricantes de navegadores decidam aderir essa recomendação seu código deixará de funcionar.
- caso precise usar métodos com [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) estará impossibilitado pois métodos de pesquisa baseados em `id` estarão comprometidos.

Para resolver o problema com os `id` eu criei um contador que é concatenado ao `id` da `<div>` dinâmica, mantendo os elementos interiores os seus respectivos identificadores.

```js
var count = 1; //Criei um contador para ser adicionad o id da <div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) $('#button').click();
  });

  $('#button').click(function() {
    var textAdd = $('#inpudAdd').val();
    $('#inpudAdd').val('');
    //Concatena o contador ao id da <div>
    $('#div').append('<div id = "divinha' + count + '"><input class = "mano" id = "check" type="checkbox"> ' + textAdd + '<img id = "lixo" src="imagens/lixeira.png" alt="" height="20px">' + '</div>');
    count++; //incrementa o contador para próxima chamada
  });


  $(document).on("change", "#check", function() {

    //O código do evento simplificado
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('marcar');

  });

  /*$(document).on("click.primeiro",'#check', function() {
      $('#divinha').addClass('seila');
      console.log("meu");
  });
  $(document).on("click.segundo",'#check', function() {
      $('#divinha').removeClass('seila')
      console.log("meu");
  });*/
  $(document).on("click", '#lixo', function() {
    if (confirm("Você realmente deseja excluir esse item?") == true) {
      $(this).parent().remove();// Não vi o botão no sandbox mas mantive o mesmo princípio adotado nos checkbox
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.marcar {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.CentralizarDiv {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 70vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.centralizarInp {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.centralizarBut {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h2 {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

table {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.secBut {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/js.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h2>Lista de Tarefas</h2>
  <input class="centralizarInp" type="text" name="checkListItem" id="inpudAdd" />
  <button class="centralizarBut " id="button">OK</button>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><button id="incopleto" class="secBut">Em Progresso</button></td>
      <td><button id="completo" class="secBut">Finalizadas</button></td>
      <td><button id="todos" class="secBut">Todos</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div class="CentralizarDiv" id="div"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nossa muito obrigado, ajudou muito!